# How to make value table LWC component dynamic

Tags: javascript, dynamic, table, design-attributes

I have the following syntax where I want to replace `'Accounts_List'` with a design value :

```
 @wire(getDynamicTableDataList, { TableName: 'Accounts_List'})
    wiredContacts({ error, data }) 
    {
        console.log(this.objectListApiName);
```

The log returns the correct value.
I tried `{ TableName:'{objectListApiName}'}` but this gives an error.

How do I replace the hardcoded `'Accounts_List'` with an @api value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactive properties for wire methods use a simple $ prefix:

```
{ TableName:'$objectListApiName'}
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about).

Comment: Thank you for helping out